# Movie Night: Return of the Jedi (and It's a Trap!)

Tags: chat-event, discussion, movie-night

In honour of the impending theatrical release of Episode VII of the *Star Wars* film franchise, let's watch Episode VI, ***The Return of the Jedi:***

[image]

To set a "standard", let's aim to watch the 2004/2006 DVD release version.  The 2011 version is only longer in one scene (as far as I can tell), and so there should be only one need to resync.  Watch other versions at your own peril.

I'm proposing **11 pm UTC** (11 pm GMT, 6 pm EST) on either **Tuesday the 15th** or **Wednesday the 16th**.

People can vote below for Tuesday or Wednesday.  I'll call a victor at 11:59 pm UTC on Sunday.

Everyone is invited, including the user who said these things:

- ["What is Star Wars?"](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/198?m=24960861#24960861)
- ["Star Wars is crap."](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/198?m=22324042#22324042)

## Update

As of 23h59 UTC on 13 Dec, both options (Tuesday the 15th and Wednesday the 16th) had an equal number of votes.

So here's what we'll do:

- On **Tuesday the 15th at 23h00 UTC**, we'll watch ***Return of the Jedi*** (the 2004/2006 or 2011 versions, which have [minimal difference in length](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_changes_in_Star_Wars_re-releases), or another version if you don't mind being out of sync) — to be hosted by our very own Wad Cheber
- On **Wednesday the 16th at 23h00 UTC**, we'll watch ***It's a Trap!***, the *Family Guy* version of *RotJ*! — to be hosted by yours truly

[image]

Comment: Given the vast array of versions of RotJ, I'm tempted to tune in just so I can laugh at you trying to coordinate things.

Comment: You may want to ask a mod to mark this as "featured" so it shows up on the main site.

Comment: Ha! :-D Thanks for including me, but I still stick to ["Never watched Star Wars, never will."](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/198?m=25876514#25876514)

Comment: @Richard : Already done.   And laugh away!  :-)

Comment: If everyone watches different versions won't we get all out of sync every time there's an edited scene?

Comment: @MikeEdenfield : I've added a version recommendation.

Comment: @Praxis - Good luck actually enforcing that.

Comment: @Richard : I'm not going to try.  As I said above, people can watch other versions at their own peril.  Also, we've all seen RotJ a million times.  It's not going to matter if someone's complaint about CGI eyelids on ewoks comes 5 minutes before someone else has gotten there.

Comment: @Praxis "we've all seen RotJ a million times": *a-**hem*** ;-)

Comment: @TARS : I already created chat events for it...do they show up for you?

Comment: @Praxis It seems they do, just not in the sideboard.

Comment: Is the Family Guy special on Netflix or any other streaming service (Hulu, Amazon) or do I have to buy a copy?

Comment: I have the 6 Disc Collection on Blu-Ray is that roughly the same?

Comment: Is there a link for the chats?

Comment: @MichaelBrown : Just visit http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/198/ at the times above!  :-)

Comment: @MichaelBrown : I believe the Blu-Ray collection is 2011.  That should be fine.  It's slightly longer in one scene than 2004/2006.  As for Family Guy, its availability on streaming services depends on your region.

Comment: You can ask a mod to add the date as a "[community event](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/admin/community-events)" and room owners can add a chat event by selecting the appropriate button under "room info"

Comment: @Richard : I thought I already did those things.  I already created the chat events days ago.  (Do they not show up for you?)  I also asked AncientSwordRage and Keen to do whatever else is necessary to give maximal exposure.

Comment: @praxis -  I can't see a featured event on the main site

Comment: @Richard : I sent Keen the community event link and asked him to add It's a Trap to it.

Comment: @Praxis - The meta post is featured, but the chat event isn't listed as a community event. You'll probably have fewer lurkers as a result.

Comment: @Richard : Thanks again for the assistance with the movie night.  I feel it is important to add, I have no intention of taking on this role permanently.  I'm just keeping the seat warm.  :-)

Comment: @Praxis - No worries. I feel like you were let down by the mods on this one, not creating the event for you properly and not advertising it for you.

Answer (score 4):

## I want to watch *RotJ* on Tuesday at 11 pm UTC.

Upvote this answer if you agree with the statement above.  (I'll only be counting upvotes, not downvotes.)

Answer (score 3):

## I want to watch *RotJ* on Wednesday at 11 pm UTC.

Upvote this answer if you agree with the statement above.  (I'll only be counting upvotes, not downvotes.)